# Conflito de condições no htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, url

Olá estou começando a tentar trabalhar com URLs amigáveis agora, então não tenho certeza que estou fazendo a coisa certa.
É o seguinte: tenho um site feito totalmente sem o uso do htaccess, então está com links enormes, andei pesquisando e para modifica-lo totalmente vai dar muito trabalho, então estou tentando usar o método de reescrever as URLs pelo htaccess.

Meu htaccess está da seguinte forma:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-(.*)$ index.php?livro=$1&capitulo=$2&versao=$3
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)$ versiculos.php?livro=$1&capitulo=$2&versiculo=$3&versao=$4
```

Tanto o index, quanto a página versículos, estão na raiz do diretório. O problema é que se eu declarar apenas a segunda condição, funciona certinho como o esperado, mas como preciso colocar também a condição da index, a segunda condição não funciona, acho que está dando algum tipo de conflito.

Como eu disse, não sei se estou fazendo alguma coisa errada. Teria alguma forma de especificar pra qual página cada condição irá servir ?

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Tente por a página de versículo, assim como outras páginas, dentro de outro diretório (no exemplo abaixo eu coloquei dentro de um sub diretório chamado "pages") e deixe apenas o index no diretório raiz. Por fim, faça as mudanças necessárias em seu htaccess como está EXATAMENTE demonstrado abaixo.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^versiculos/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ pages/versiculos.php?livro=$1&capitulo=$2&versiculo=$3&versao=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ index.php?livro=$1&capitulo=$2&versao=$3 [NC,L]
```

OBS1: Note que usei a flag L em cada reescrita de url que é para por uma espécie de break para quando o apache encontrar a regra. Além disso eu troquei a ordem das regras da mais especifica, no caso a regra dos versiculos, para a regra menos especifica, que no exemplo representa a regra do index.

OBS2: Quando voce invocar a url de versiculos deve ficar assim : minhapagina/versiculos/parametro1/parametro2/parametro3/parametro4/, mas isso voce mudar depois, caso queira.